# Symfony2 Dynamic Form Modification not saving generated data

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm going crazy because if I choose a client from an entity field, it correctly populate the second entity field called proposals. Then I choose the proposal dynamically generated, but when I save the form it saves the form correctly but without filling the proposal field. I followed the Symfony Tutorial about the Dynamic Forms which can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

This is my FormType code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('client', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Client',
            'property' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Client:',
            'empty_value' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
        },
        ));


 $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Client $client = null) {

        $proposals = null === $client ? array() : $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Proposals')->findBy(
            array('client'=>$client->getId()),
            array('id' => 'DESC'));

        $form->add('proposal', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Proposal',
            'choice_label' => 'subject',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $proposals,
            'label' => 'Proposal',
            'required' => false
        ));
    };

  $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $client = null;
            $data = $event->getData();
            if(!empty($data)) {
                $client = $data->getClient();
            }
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $client );
        }
    );

   $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            $client = $event->getForm()->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
        }
    );
```

This is the Prenotazione Entity, the one who belong the form.

```
class Prenotazione {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="prenotazioni")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $client;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Proposal", inversedBy="prenotazione")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proposal_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $proposal;




public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}


public function setProposal(\AppBundle\Entity\Proposal $proposal = null)
{
    $this->proposal = $proposal;

    return $this;
}

public function getProposal() {
    return $this->proposal;
}


public function setClient(\AppBundle\Entity\Client $client = null)
{
    $this->client = $client;

    return $this;
}


public function getClient()
{
    return $this->client;
}
```

}

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: can you show us your entity?

Comment: I second @PawełMikołajczuk.

Comment: added in the question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your proposals query is correct?

```
$proposals = null === $client ? array() : $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Proposals')->findBy(
    array('client'=>$client->getId()),
    array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

Shouldn't this be either `array('client_id' => $client->getId()),` or `array('client' => $client),`?

Try checking the actual content of $proposals by adding a `dump($proposals)` just below and looking up the result in the symfony profiler.

Comment: you mean var_dump ? Never heard about dump function and when I try it it gives me an error. The code is fine even with 'client'=>$client works fine. The results returned are fine. The only big problem is that it doesn't save my choice